# Help with the quest "Oh my Papa!"

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I finished the quest "Don't make a beggar of me" and later I started "Oh my Papa!". I went to talk to Melissa but she is gone, according to the wiki this may happen sometimes. Since I am on PC is there any command or something I could do to fix this? I want to finish this quest by the diplomatic way, wich means no bloodbath.

Answer (score 2):

`player.placeatme 000e595c` where `000e595c` is Melissa's Base ID which I got from her [Wikia page](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Melissa_Lewis), should put her right on top of you.

That should make finding her a lot easier.

Comment: You want the RefId (000e5e51 for Melissa). PlaceAtMe will spawn a copy, and you end up with two Melissa's in your game.

Comment: If his original Melissa is gone, there would only be one.